# CSS applied only to odd rows

Tags: java, css, javafx-2

I have a table view populated with Samples objects. I want to fill the TableRow if a property of the Samples object = true. I used a method based on this answer of jewelsea: [Disable TableRow based on data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10925882/disable-tablerow-based-on-data)

```
int i = 0;
if (tblSamples.getItems().size() > 0) {
    for (Node n : tblSamples.lookupAll("TableRow")) {
        if (n instanceof TableRow) {
            TableRow row = (TableRow) n;
            row.getStyleClass().removeAll("hasMastitisRow");

            if (tblSamples.getItems().get(i).getClinicalMastitis()) {
                row.getStyleClass().add("hasMastitisRow");
            }
            i++;

            if (i == tblSamples.getItems().size()) {
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

CSS:

```
.hasMastitisRow {  
    -fx-control-inner-background: linear-gradient(#FFFFFF 85%, red 100%);
}
```

However, it only applies on odd rows, on even rows it does not seem to work?

Edit: it also seems I get following errors when the CSS is applied to even rows (on odd rows I get no errors):

```
WARNING: com.sun.javafx.css.StyleHelper calculateValue Could not resolve '-fx-table-cell-border-color' while resolving lookups for '-fx-background-color' from rule '*.table-row-cell:odd' in stylesheet jar:file:/C:/Program%20Files/Java/jdk1.7.0_15/jre/lib/jfxrt.jar!/com/sun/javafx/scene/control/skin/caspian/caspian.bss
WARNING: com.sun.javafx.css.StyleHelper calculateValue Could not resolve '-fx-control-inner-background' while resolving lookups for '-fx-text-fill' from rule '*.table-cell' in stylesheet jar:file:/C:/Program%20Files/Java/jdk1.7.0_15/jre/lib/jfxrt.jar!/com/sun/javafx/scene/control/skin/caspian/caspian.bss
WARNING: com.sun.javafx.css.StyleHelper calculateValue Could not resolve '-fx-control-inner-background' while resolving lookups for '-fx-text-fill' from rule '*.table-cell' in stylesheet jar:file:/C:/Program%20Files/Java/jdk1.7.0_15/jre/lib/jfxrt.jar!/com/sun/javafx/scene/control/skin/caspian/caspian.bss
WARNING: com.sun.javafx.css.StyleHelper calculateValue Could not resolve '-fx-control-inner-background' while resolving lookups for '-fx-text-fill' from rule '*.table-cell' in stylesheet jar:file:/C:/Program%20Files/Java/jdk1.7.0_15/jre/lib/jfxrt.jar!/com/sun/javafx/scene/control/skin/caspian/caspian.bss
WARNING: com.sun.javafx.css.StyleHelper calculateValue Could not resolve '-fx-control-inner-background' while resolving lookups for '-fx-text-fill' from rule '*.table-row-cell' in stylesheet jar:file:/C:/Program%20Files/Java/jdk1.7.0_15/jre/lib/jfxrt.jar!/com/sun/javafx/scene/control/skin/caspian/caspian.bss
WARNING: com.sun.javafx.css.StyleHelper calculateValue Could not resolve '-fx-table-cell-border-color' while resolving lookups for '-fx-background-color' from rule '*.table-row-cell:odd' in stylesheet jar:file:/C:/Program%20Files/Java/jdk1.7.0_15/jre/lib/jfxrt.jar!/com/sun/javafx/scene/control/skin/caspian/caspian.bss
WARNING: com.sun.javafx.css.StyleHelper calculateValue Could not resolve '-fx-control-inner-background' while resolving lookups for '-fx-text-fill' from rule '*.table-cell' in stylesheet jar:file:/C:/Program%20Files/Java/jdk1.7.0_15/jre/lib/jfxrt.jar!/com/sun/javafx/scene/control/skin/caspian/caspian.bss
WARNING: com.sun.javafx.css.StyleHelper calculateValue Could not resolve '-fx-control-inner-background' while resolving lookups for '-fx-text-fill' from rule '*.table-cell' in stylesheet jar:file:/C:/Program%20Files/Java/jdk1.7.0_15/jre/lib/jfxrt.jar!/com/sun/javafx/scene/control/skin/caspian/caspian.bss
WARNING: com.sun.javafx.css.StyleHelper calculateValue Could not resolve '-fx-control-inner-background' while resolving lookups for '-fx-text-fill' from rule '*.table-cell' in stylesheet jar:file:/C:/Program%20Files/Java/jdk1.7.0_15/jre/lib/jfxrt.jar!/com/sun/javafx/scene/control/skin/caspian/caspian.bss
```

**edit:**
New approach but still the same result (applied on odd rows, not on even rows):

```
tc_Samples_Quarter.setCellFactory(new Callback<TableColumn<Samples, String>, TableCell<Samples, String>>() {
        @Override
        public TableCell<Samples, String> call(TableColumn<Samples, String> soCalledSampleRowStringTableColumn) {
            return new TableCell<Samples, String>() {
                @Override
                public void updateItem(final String item, final boolean empty) {
                    super.updateItem(item, empty);
                    this.getTableRow().getStyleClass().remove("hasMastitisRow");
                    if (item != null) {
                        setText(item);
                        this.getTableRow().getStyleClass().add("hasMastitisRow");
                    } else {
                        setText(null);
                    }
                }
            };
        }
    });
```

Comment: Can you post a jsfiddle?

Comment: No idea what a jsfiddle is, but that seems to be for javascript? I program in java using netbeans and the program runs as a java webstart..

Comment: It's just a name, you can ignore the JavaScript window if you don't have any that's relevant to the question.  Just paste your compiled HTML and CSS in the appropriate window and save it:  http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: That's the point, I don't have any HTML as it is written in Java (java webstart application)

Comment: `nth-child(odd)` and `nth-child(even)` selectors might work better

Comment: See section 'constructor' at http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/control/TableRow.html
`table-row-cell { -fx-control-inner-background: linear-gradient(#FFFFFF 85%, red 100%); }` should work to select all the rows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has been fixed by using the setCellFactory solution (see the other aproach in the question above) and by adjusting the CSS to:

```
.hasMastitisRow {  
    -fx-background-color: linear-gradient(#FFFFFF 85%, red 100%);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Curious about some of your code.  First you are fetching your nodes like:

```
for (Node n : tblSamples.lookupAll("TableRow")) {
```

then you do an instance of check to see if it is a TableRow

```
if (n instanceof TableRow) {
```

is that necessary?  Is there a possibility that the **lookupAll** will return nodes that are not TableRow's?  If so, then one possibility might be that the increment of the **i** index is only taking place inside the **if (n instanceof TableRow)** so **i** is only incremented if it is a TableRow.  Could it be that **i** is not matching the items in the index because it isn't keeping up with the loop?

Comment: I do not think it is needed as all objects should be TableRow, however it seems that the incrementation is working correctly. However I tried another approach using cellfactory (added in original post) but still the same results, which I thinks means its CSS related?

Comment: I still lean towards the indexing.  You are looping through a subset of nodes that are TableRows with your **for** loop, but then inside that loop you are doing a **tblSamples.getItems().get(i)**.  How do you know the list returned from the **getItems()** call is equivalent to the list returned from the **tblSamples.lookupAll("TableRow")**?  If they are not the same list, then the **get(i)** is not necessarily returning the node you think it is.

Comment: Hi Jere, yes I can follow your thinking path.. however when working with the CellFactory instead (so without incrementation) it's the same issue, that's why I think it is a CSS problem rather than a method issue?

Comment: Perhaps a debugging suggestion --- define a unique id associated with each of your items in the items list, then set that as a user data property on the TableRow when that is constructed.  Then inside your loop, print out the user data for the **row** and the identifier for the **getItems().get(i)** to see if they match.