# How to disable some rows in TableView

Tags: javafx, tableview

I have the following TableView (JavaFX 2.2.45):

```
Period   Number   Number   Number
---------------------------------
1          x         x       x
2          x         x       x
3          x         x       x
.
.
24         x         x       x
```

The period column represents hour of a day. The number columns are editable. I want to be able to disable rows before and including the current hour. So for example, if it is 10:15 I want to disable rows 1 through 11. How can I use the current hour (which is easy to calculate and put in a variable) to accomplish this?

Comment: I first tried the strategies mentioned in the top answer of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10925882/disable-tablerow-based-on-data  but could not get those to work. Now I have a working solution based on a custom cellFactory and a BooleanProperty in the table model, but think I should try again with rowFactory which seems a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

In the end, `TableView.setRowFactory()` works fine for this. I newed up this class as parameter to `setRowFactory` (generics omitted for brevity):

```java
public class LockableRow implements Callback {

    @Override
    public TableRow call(TableView tableView) {
        return new TableRow() {
            @Override
            protected void updateItem(LockableModel item, boolean empty) {
                super.updateItem(item, empty);
                if (!isEmpty()) {
                    if (isRowDisabled(tableView, getIndex())) {
                        setDisable(true);
                    } else {
                        setDisable(false);
                    }
                }
            }
        };
    }

    private boolean isRowDisabled(TableView tableView, int thisRow) {
        ObservableList rows = tableView.getItems();
        return (thisRow< rows.size() && rows.get(thisRow).isDisabled());
    }
}
```

Here, the model backing the table view is `LockableModel` which implements `isDisabled()`.